# I'm looking for a function like this

Tags: functions

The depends on two variables: $A$ and $B$.

$f(x)$, where $x\in [0,1]$

$f(x)$ has a maximum at $x=A$.

$x \in [A-B, A+B] \implies f(x) \approx 1$

$x \in [0, A-B] \cup [A+B, 1] \implies f(x) \approx 0$

Example: [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a nonpiecewise smooth function, choose a large integer $n$ ($n=10$ looked pretty good when I plotted), and try $$e^{-\left(\frac{(x-A)(1 - 1/(2n))^{1/(2n)}}{B}\right)^{2n}}$$

This is a modification of the Gaussian bell curve, shifted with the "$-A$", and steepened by replacing the exponent of $2$ with $2n$. Then figure out where the new inflection point would be and rescale horizontally to move it to be $B$ units away from $A$.

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is $$f(z)= \begin {cases}0& x\lt A-B\\1&A-B\le x \lt A+B\\0&A+B\le x \end{cases}$$

Maybe you don't like the discontinuities. You can fill them in with steep straight lines or use the difference of two logistic functions, one that rises around A-B and one that rises around A+B.

These ignore the max at A, but you can add a bit for that. There are many choices that meet what you asked.